# Why does most galaxies resemble a 2 dimensional plane?

Tags: classical-mechanics, cosmology, atomic-physics, galaxies, accretion-disk

Older galaxies mostly tend the revolve forming a disk. Why are the stars not revolving around the center of the galaxy like a sphere instead similar to electron in an atom?

Comment: The title mentions the Solar System, but the question body doesn't, and the answers to the two cases are rather different in detail. Perhaps just ask about one (at a time)?

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/93830/2451 , http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/8502/2451 , http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/12140/2451 , http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/26083/2451 , and links therein.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are [other shapes of galaxies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galaxy_morphological_classification). In particular, look at ellipticals.

Comment: All of them are also disk shaped.

Comment: No they aren't. Look at the pictures in Rob  Jeffries' answer http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/148418/why-arent-there-spherical-galaxies