# Star vs Blackhole - Accretion Disk

Tags: gravity, black-holes, angular-momentum, stars, accretion-disk

Simple question: can we prove that what we call today a "star" is not a accretion disk of a "tiny" black hole that happens to rotate in all the 3 axis?

Comment: An object can't rotate in all three axes because that wouldn't conserve angular momentum. A black hole + accretion disk must have axial symmetry not spherical symmetry. Accretion disks have a competely different spectrum to stars. In particular they radiate lots of X-rays. Bearing in mind how closely we've observed our own star it can't possibly be a black hole + accretion disk.

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/26083/2451 , http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/93830/2451 and links therein.

Comment: Also, the Doppler profile will be much more pronounced for an accretion disk, as opposed to a star, due to the much higher speeds.