# Why are black holes depicted as disks and not spheres?

Tags: black-holes, angular-momentum, orbital-motion, event-horizon

Surely light gets 'pulled' in from all directions in 3D space so the event horizon would not be a round disk, but rather a sphere of light - meaning black holes should actually be light holes?

My only guess is it would be due to the same phenomenon that causes our solar systems, planet rings and galaxies shapes to generally be 2-dimensional rather than spherical.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Static black holes are spheres while rotating black holes have an oblate horizon so they are a deformed sphere. I suspect you are thinking of the [accretion disk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Accretion_disk) when you say *Why are black holes depicted as disks and not spheres?*, and this is indeed [the same reason that galaxies form disks](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/93830/why-the-galaxies-form-2d-planes-or-spiral-like-instead-of-3d-balls-or-spheric).